Lemma relating to the Fundamental Lemma of the Calculus of Variation
Recently I started reading "A First Course in the Calculus of Variations" by Mark Kot. One of the exercises in that book requires the reader to prove the following lemma:

Let $M(x)\in C[a,b]$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $a\leq x\leq b$ that satisfies $$\int_a^b M(x)\eta''(x)dx=0$$
for all $\eta(x)\in C^2[a,b]$ satisfying $$\eta(a)=\eta(b)=\eta'(a)=\eta'(b)=0.$$
Prove that $$M(x)=c_0+c_1x$$ for suitable constants $c_0$ and $c_1$. What can you say about $c_0$ and $c_1$?

I have little clue on what to do. I tried to mimic the proof of the two similar lemmas presented in the book, which are the Fundamental Lemma of the Calculus of Variations and du Bois-Reymand Lemma, but I still got stuck.
Could someone provide some hints on what I can try?
I have attached the two lemmas and their proofs here as well. Fundamental Lemma of the Calculus of Variations and Its Proof and du Bois-Reymand Lemma and Its Proof.

Perhaps you could using integration by parts to show that $M'' =0$?

Hey, copper.hat I don't think integration by Parts can be applied directly to the integral, because we do not know $M$ is differentiable. However, I did try to use Stone-Weierstrass's Theorem to approximate $M$ using polynomials, but in that case, I still wasn't able to prove the desired statement.

For $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$, define $\eta:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$\eta(x)=\int_a^x\int_a^t(M(\xi)-A\xi-B)\,\mathrm{d}\xi\,\mathrm{d}t.$$
I'll leave it up to you to check that $A$ and $B$ can be chosen such that
$$\eta(b)=\eta'(b)=0$$
(simply compute the integrals of the polynomial and solve the resulting system of equations); fix such $A,B$. Now it is clear that also $\eta(a)=\eta'(a)=0$, so by assumption we have that
$$\int_a^bM(x)\eta''(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0.$$
Observe also that
$$\int_a^b(Ax+B)\eta''(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\underbrace{\biggl[(Ax+B)\eta'(x)\biggr]_a^b}_{=0}-A\int_a^b\eta'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-A\underbrace{\biggl[\eta(x)\biggr]_a^b}_{=0}=0.$$
Consequently, as
$$\eta''(x)=M(x)-Ax-B,$$
we have that
$$\int_a^b(M(x)-Ax-B)^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_a^bM(x)\eta''(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_a^b(Ax+B)\eta''(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0.$$
But this implies that $(M(x)-Ax-B)^2=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, and so
$$M(x)=Ax+B$$
for all $x\in[a,b]$.

We begin by proving the following Lemma:

Let $w \in C^2(a, b)$ be such that $$\int_a^b w(x)\,dx = 0, \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \int_a^b x w(x)\,dx = 0.$$ Then $$\int_a^b M(x)w(x) \,dx = 0.$$

Proof: let $$\eta(x) := \int_a^x \int_a^t w(s)\,dsdt.$$ Clealy $\eta \in C^2(a, b)$. Moreover, it satisfies $$\eta'(x) = \int_a^x w(s)\,ds,$$ and therefore $$\eta'(a) = 0 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \eta'(b) = \int_a^b w(s)\,ds = 0.$$
Notice also that $\eta(a) = 0$ and $$\eta(b) = \int_a^b \int_a^t w(s)\,ds = \int_a^b \int_{s}^b w(s)\,dtds = \int_a^b w(s)(b - s)\,ds = 0.$$
Since $\eta$ has all the desired properties, by assumption we have that $$0 = \int_a^b M(x)\eta''(x)\,dx = \int_a^b M(x)w(x)\,dx,$$ as we claimed above.

Take any function $\varphi \in C^2(a, b)$ and modify it to obtain a function $w$ as in the Lemma above. As suggested by daw in the comments to this answer, it suffices to take $w := (I - P)\varphi$, where $P$ denotes the $L^2$-projection onto the space of affine functions (that is, onto the space of polynomials of degree 1). In order to simplify the computations, assume that $a = -1/2, b = 1/2$. Then $\{1,\frac{x}{\sqrt{12}}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the space of affine functions on $(-1/2, 1/2)$. Hence, given $\varphi \in C^2$, its projection onto this space is $$P \varphi(x) : = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} 1 \cdot \varphi(t)\,dt + \frac{x}{\sqrt{12}}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \frac{t}{\sqrt{12}}\varphi(t)\,dt.$$ This leads to defining $$w(x) := \varphi(x) - P\varphi(x) = \varphi(x) - \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\varphi(t)\,dt + \frac{x}{12}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} t\varphi(t)\,dt.$$ Since by construction we have that $w$ satisfies the assumption of the Lemma above in this answer, we can conclude that $$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} M(x)w(x)\,dx = 0.$$
The rest follows by noticing that the integral above can be rewritten as $$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}(I - P)M(x) \varphi(x)\,dx$$ either by checking the computations by hand, or by using (as daw suggested) the fact that this is self-adjoint.

One can set $w:= (I - P)\phi$, where $P$ is the projection onto affine linear functions in the $L^2(a,b)$-inner product. This is a self-adjoint operator, so that $\tilde M = (I-P)M$.

@daw: That's an excellent way to put it. For the OP: this way of looking at it also helps with computing what $w$ is. Indeed, for $a = -1/2, b = 1/2$ all we need to do is subtract off from $\varphi$ it projection onto affine functions, that is $w(x) = \varphi(x) - \int \varphi(t),dt - \frac{x}{12}\int t \varphi(t)dt$.

(A) How can we know whether $w$ exists , when you take "Let $w\cdots$ such that ..." ? (B) How can we know whether OP lemma holds for all other valid $\eta$ ?

@Giovanni: Thank you for your hint. I get that if $\tilde{M}=(I-P)M$, then $\int \tilde{M}(x)\varphi(x)dx=0$ for any $\varphi$ would imply that $\tilde{M}$ being $0$, hence $M$ being an affine function. However, could you explain a bit more on the relationship between $w$ and $\varphi$, in terms of how to getting from an arbitrary $\varphi$ to $w$. I don't see directly why the projection onto the affine linear functions work.

@TheLittleE : I've edited my answer to clarify the relationship between those two functions. I hope this helps!

@Giovanni: Thank you, I understand now!

Proof :
$$I = \int_a^b M(x)\eta''(x)dx = 0$$
Integrate By Parts :
$$I = \color{gray}{[M(x)\eta'(x)]_a^b} - \int_a^b M'(x)\eta'(x)dx$$
Here the gray Part is $0$.
Integrate By Parts :
$$I = - \color{gray}{[M'(x)\eta(x)]_a^b} + \int_a^b M''(x)\eta(x)dx$$
Here the gray Part is $0$.
$$I = \int_a^b M''(x)\eta(x)dx = 0$$
We are given that $I$ is $0$ for all valid $\eta$
Let $\eta=\eta_1$ be a valid function with Positive & Negative values in $(a,b)$ , where we are given that $I=0$.
Example $\eta=(x-a)(x-b)(x-(a+b)/2)$
Naturally , the negative values of $M''(x)\eta(x)$ are "canceled" by the Positive values of that area under the curve to yield $I=0$ total.
We can easily see that $\eta=|\eta_1|$ is also a valid function , though it has only Positive values in $(a,b)$ , yet $I=0$.
That means that there were no Positive values & no Negative values of $M''(x)\eta(x)$ , even though we could control $\eta(x)$.
That means $M''(x) \equiv 0$
That means $M'(x) \equiv c_1$
That means $M(x) \equiv c_0+c_1x0$
END of Proof

ADDITIONAL DETAILS :
In response to OP "Could someone provide some hints on what I can try?"
What to try :
(1) Adjusting $M$ :
(1A) Check that $M(x)=c_0+c_1x$ works to get Integral $0$
(1B) Check whether higher terms will work.
$M(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_bx^n$ will not work when $m=2,3,\cdots$
(2) Alternately , we can adjust $\eta$ :
(2A) It is given that the Integral is $0$ for all $\eta(x)$ , hence we can use $\eta(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$
We will see that $0$ Integral will restrict $M$
(2B) We can use $\eta(x)=x^n(x-a)(x-b)$
We will see that $0$ Integral will restrict $M$ further.
Eventually , that will give linear $M$

Hello Prem. I don't think integration by part can be applied directly as $M(x)$ may not be differentiable.
